# Changing locale for thymeleaf utility objects

Tags: spring, spring-boot, localization, thymeleaf

I want to use `#dates` or `#calendars` to get a list of the elapsed months of the current year. This can be achieved using `${#dates.monthName(date)}` and a bit of logic, but the name of the months comes in english, and I need it in spanish.

Is there a way to tell thymeleaf to use one locale or another? I've read it uses the standard Date and Calendar from Java, so maybe some sort of application settings for this classes in spring would work?

Comment: It will pick from the locale Spring runs in. I verified this with one of our applications.Just in case you need more information on how we do the locale management, I can share the code in the answer below

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've to use the method *monthName(Object target, Locale locale)* of Thymeleaf [DateUtils](https://www.thymeleaf.org/apidocs/thymeleaf/2.1.5.RELEASE/org/thymeleaf/util/DateUtils.html).
I think something like this should work:

```
${T(org.thymeleaf.util.DateUtils).monthName(#dates.createNow(), #locale.getDefault())}
```